# Why TextBox's caret jumps to the beginning of text after input?

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox, caret

I have a user control, it contains an image and a TextBox, after I input in the text box, the cursor like caret jumps to the beginning of the text in the text box, how can I debug why this happens?

I know this code can put the caret at beginning: textBox1.Select(0, 0);
But I don't have any code like this, and I tried textBox1.Select(text.Length-1, 0) this will put the caret at the end of the text. How can I make sure the caret is after the latest input no matter where the latest input letter is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `Text` property of `TextBox` programmatically, then it will automatically put the caret at the begining. So, I think you have subscribed to the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and you have put some code like `myTextBox.Text = "some text";` in the event handler.

When user changes the `Text`, `TextChanged` event is fired, your event handler changes the `Text` again, as a result, the caret is set to the beginning.

So, it's not because of any *fault* of your code. This is the default behavior of `TextBox`, now, whether it's a feature or a bug, that's disputable.

I also faced this and my solution was to put the cursor at the end programmatically if any programmatic text changing was needed, with this code at the end of the event handler:

```
myTextBox.Select(myTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

Hope that helps.